# Sequelize join multiples fields - multiples tables

Tags: mysql, join, relationship, sequelize.js

Can I convert the query below for sequelize?
I set up a simple example to illustrate the idea, which is basically to compare the same table with more than one table.
This
        ***TableC.field_4 = tableB.field_4
        AND TableC.field_1 = tableA.field_1*** and this 
***(
            tableA.field_8 = 1
            OR TableC.field_4 IS NOT NULL
        )***

```
var TableA = sequelize.define('TableA', 
field_1 : {
   type : Sequelize.BIGINT,
primaryKey : true,
autoIncrement : true
},

field_2 : {
    type : Sequelize.BIGINT,
},

field_3 : {
   type : Sequelize.BIGINT(4),
   references : {
       model : 'TableD',
      key : 'field_3'
   }
},

field_8 : {
type : Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
allowNull : false,
    defaultValue : true
},
{
     tableName : 'tableA'
}
);



var TableB = sequelize.define('TableB', {

field_4 : {
type : Sequelize.BIGINT(4),
primaryKey : true,
autoIncrement : true
},

field_3 : {
    type : Sequelize.BIGINT(4),
    references : {
        model : 'TableD',
        key : 'field_3'
    },
    allowNull : false
},

field_5 : {
    type : Sequelize.STRING(255),
    unique : true,
    allowNull : false
},

field_6 : {
    type : Sequelize.STRING
},

field_7 : {
    type : Sequelize.BIGINT,
    allowNull : false
},

{   
    tableName : 'tableB'
}
);



var TableC = sequelize.define('TableC', {

field_4: {
    type: Sequelize.BIGINT(4),
    primaryKey: true
    references: {
    model: 'TableB',
     key: 'field_4'
     }
},

field_1: {
    type: Sequelize.BIGINT,
    primaryKey: true
    references: {
    model: 'TableA',
    key: 'field_1'
     }
},

{
tableName: 'tableC'
}
);

SELECT
    *
FROM
    tableA
JOIN tableB ON
    tableB.field_3 = tableA.field_3
LEFT JOIN TableC ON
    TableC.field_4 = tableB.field_4
    AND TableC.field_1 = tableA.field_1
WHERE
    (
        tableA.field_8 = 1
        OR TableC.field_4 IS NOT NULL
    )
    and tableB.field_7 = 10
    and tableA.field_2 = 1036
```